# Android Native to React Native bridge

Tags: android, react-native, native-module

I've been searching on how to make a bridge between React Native and Android Native code for a while, but I still don't quite get it. I've read the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html) , but I don't quite understand it.
What I want to do is, I want to build an apps that utilize push notification, but since I need to push message to China, I can't use GCM (thanks to the great firewall), so I use another third party push SDK.

I've managed to integrate the push into my apps (resulting a `console.log()` message whenever I push something), the next step is I want to re-route it to certain page

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: If you are using common push notification (i.e. GCM and APNS), use [this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) instead. Since I need to use another third party push service, I need to find a way myself to bridge the SDK (which is native) to React Native.

So after several hours tinkering with this problem, I found a solution for my problem. This solution divided into 2 parts:

1. `emitter`, this will emits an event whenever the server send a push.
2. `listener`, this will listen to the event that you emits before.

**emitter**

This happens on the native side (Android in my case)

For this part I learnt it from how [this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library did using GCM. And found a tutorial [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript) on the RN documentation.

Basically after you receive your push on `SomeBroadCastReceiver onReceive()` function, you can pass the bundle as params in this function

```
reactContext
  .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
  //this eventName is a key so you need to remember it, because you need to call it on the listener
  .emit(eventName, params);
```

**listener**

The listener will be built on the RN side. this [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript) helps me. I missed this documentation before, because it only appear in the RN iOS docs only.

```
import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
//import your already created package name here
const { YourCustomPackageName} = NativeModules;
```

then in `ComponentWillMount()`

```
const yourCustomPackageEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(YourCustomPackageName);
pushListenerEmitter.addListener(eventName, this.handlePush, this);
```

then you just need to create `handlePush` function and get the params there

```
handlePush = (event) => {
    console.log('event triggered..');
    console.log(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do push notification is Deep Linking. If you are using React Navigation its much simple to do. [Deep Linking React Native](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html)
You can define unique URL like yorApp://employee/1 and navigate easily to that screen.